# Cancel basic authentitcation in Protractor test

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

I have some AngularJS application which I want to end-to-end test with Protractor. The problem I have is that there is an Iframe on the page which loads some information to show to the user. This content is protected with HTTP basic auth.

To test the application this content is not important at all. (I can't log in because I don't have credentials and I don't want to have credentials in the test or config.)

So I want to cancel the request somehow, or click on the cancel button in the popup:

[image: Basic Authentication]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can execute javascript from the browser object, it is possible to remove the `iframe` element from the dom, even after the authentication request is completed (removing the popup). This solves the problem because it will not ask to authenticate during a protractor test.

I put this code in my `beforeEach`:

```
browser.executeScript(
    'document.querySelector("iframe").remove();'
);
```

And it worked like a charm.